# RuntimeError: working outside of request context Flask Session

Tags: python, api, unit-testing, flask, session

I am getting **RuntimeError: working outside of request context** error while running a test in Flask. I've tried multiple suggestions from other threads, but none has worked for me.

Part of my views.py:

```
    @user_app.route('/login', methods =('GET', 'POST'))
    def login():
        form = LoginForm()
        error = None
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            user = User.objects.filter(username=form.username.data).first()
            if user:
                if bc.hashpw(form.password.data, user.password) == user.password:
                    session['username']=form.username.data
                    return 'User Logged In'
                else:
                    user = None
            if not user:
                error = 'Incorrect credentials'

        return render_template('user/login.html',form=form,error=error)
```

Relevant part of my tests.py:

```
    from application import create_app as create_app_base

    def create_app(self):
        self.db_name = 'flaskbook_test'
        return create_app_base(
            MONGODB_SETTINGS={'DB':self.db_name},
            TESTING=True,
            WTF_CSRF_ENABLED=False,
            SECRET_KEY='SecretKey'
        )

    def setUp(self):
        self.app_factory = self.create_app()
        self.app = self.app_factory.test_client()
        #self.app.application.app_context().push() <-- this did not help

    def tearDown(self):
        db = _get_db()
        db.client.drop_database(db)

    def test_login_user(self):
        #create user
        self.app.post('/register', data=self.user_dict())
        #login user
        rv = self.app.post('/login',data=dict(
            username='username',
            password='password'
        ))
        #check session is set
        with self.app as c:
            rv = c.get('/')
        assert session.get('username') == self.user_dict()['username']
```

I have already tried adding app_context and `self.app.application.app_context().push()` as mentioned above:

```
    with self.app.application.app_context():
        assert session.get('username') == self.user_dict()['username']
```

But it didn't work. **Whenever I call `session['username']` I get RuntimeError: working outside of request context.**

My requirements.txt: Flask0.10.1 Flask-Script 2.0.5 flask-mongoengine 0.7.4

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is the [request context](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/reqcontext/), not the [app context](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/appcontext/).

Flask includes some handy functions to push a request context for you - check out the [Flask testing docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/testing/) and you'll see a lot of relevant info, including the `test_request_context` method on the app object.

Combine that with `app.test_client` to push a request context and then simulate client behaviour such as POSTing to your endpoint. Try this:

```
with self.app.test_request_context('/'), self.app.test_client() as c:
    rv = c.post('/')
    assert session.get('username') == self.user_dict()['username']
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Would you know by any chance why 'username' could be undefined in this session? In my views I set session username and the code does run it.

Comment: In my example it was just pushing a context, not actually doing a `POST` to the endpoint. I'll update it with a more detailed example. Note that since I don't know what your login form looks like, you'll need to modify this example to post any required form data yourself. (Probably a lot of googlable solutions for that)